# I need to remove add-apt-repository gnome3 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, gnome

I have installed the following repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

How do I uninstall it now? Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `--remove` flag.

`sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:repo_name/subdirectory`

Answer (score 5):

The --remove flag produces an error:

```
Usage: add-apt-repository [options] repository

add-apt-repository: error: no such option: --remove
```

Instead use the rm command to remove the file corresponding to the added repository from your sources.list.d folder; if you are using saucy, the command would look like this:

> sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome3-team-gnome3-saucy.list

Comment: Is that for "add-apt-repository" or "apt-add-repository"?

Both show the --remove option in the man page, as far as I can see.